# no suitable method found for print(int,boolean,char,double) error?

Tags: java

I was trying to print (int, boolean, char, double) in a same println statement .

```
class Test1
{
public static void main(String s[])
{
int a =5;
char c = 'a';
boolean b = true;
double d = 12.46;

System.out.println(a,b,c,d);
/*System.out.println(a); // Here it works fine
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);*/
}
}
```

> Test1.java:10: error: no suitable method found for
>   println(int,boolean,char,double)

But I don't why this error come . When i am printing this in different  different statement works fine .
Please Explain this .

Comment: That error comes because it's not valid code.  Try `a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ", " + d`.

Comment: I don't understand I don't ask that much silly question just I was not clear from that point . Why people downvote this question. But thanks to all who answer this.

Comment: please I appeal not to downcast this question. I am not able to ask any more question on this site.please

Comment: Your question is being downvoted/closed because it is clear you haven't done much research. If you search 'Java API System.out.println' you will quickly find the method signature of that method (println), which clearly takes a single string argument. You cannot pass it four such arguments. Oli showed you how to combine four strings into one, so regardless you have your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) method of `PrintStream` (of which `out` is an instance) takes a single argument. Perhaps you were you thinking of [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead.

```
System.out.printf("%d, %b, %c, %f%n", a, b, c, d);
```

```
5, true, a, 12.460000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println("" + a + b + c + d);
```

You're passing in multiple arguments into the println function, it should work if you pass it all in as a single argument.

Answer (score 2):

`println` just takes single argument. You  can achieve this with

```
System.out.println(""+ a + b + c + d );
```

Would suggest you to look at `toString` method also, where you need to `override` this.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Oli, the way to do it in Java with println, is to concatenate your values together with +. For example:

```
System.out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ", " + d);
```

Would output:

```
5, true, a, 12.46
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass multiple values at a time to `println();`

There are [individual methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) for each datatypes.

Un comment your code.That is the only way to `print`.

```
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(d);
```

println have  arg types  like

```
public void println(boolean x)
public void println(char x)
public void println(int x)...and so on
```

So you Cannot pass multiple values at a time.or simply append  them to String

```
System.out.println("" + a + b + c + d);
```